# Disable spacebar in iOS keyboard

Tags: ios, uikeyboard

In my app, I have a text field that accepts a limited number of characters and so don't want the user to be able to add a space between characters if/when they press the spacebar. Instead I would like the spacebar to be unresponsive or do another function like capitalise instead of adding a space.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1304321/iphone-restrict-user-from-entering-space-in-textfield

Comment: It's a old question.

Comment: use a keyboard of type emailField, it doesn't have a space

Comment: @sasquatch `UIKeyboardTypeEmailAddress` does have a space in it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use below delegate method of UITextField and disallow the space key. This is in Objective-C.

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
    if ( [string isEqualToString:@" "] ){
        return NO;
    }
    else {
        return YES;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

**In Swift**

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    if string == " " {
        return false
    } else {
        return true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Please go with below Code to identify spacebar.

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    if ( [string isEqualToString:@" "] && range.length==0)
    {
        return NO;
    }
    else 
    {
        return YES;
    }
}
```